# Download data from a website using python requests

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to download the data from this website: https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx. 
My questions are (1) how I can set the appropriate "payload" and post to the url for the three inputs: available products, report period end date and available file formats and (2)how I can get the link of the files since in the website, there is a download button (i can't get the link by right clicking on the button). Sorry that my questions are basic but i hope someone can provide me step-by-step guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t manipulate the web page (selecting from drop downs etc) with just requests.

You need to use dev tools to capture the URL you’re redirected to when you submit the form, then use requests to call that URL with the parameters it expects.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be a bit more specific on the dev tools to capture URL?

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools network tab. Submit the form and see where the request goes.